# Updating number of errors on field change using jQuery Validation

Tags: jquery, validation

How would I go about making the number of errors in the title instantly reflect the number of errors in the form, on field change?

```
<h6 class="error" style="font-size: 1.5em; font-weight: bold; color: #d0011b;">
    <span class="numOfErrors"></span> occurred.
</h6>
```

The standard behavior right now is that the validation itself works on change, but the error number displayed in the **title** updates only on Submit. I'd like it to update on change.

I've read the documentation for validation and can't seem to locate a built-in way of achieving this. I tried storing the visible list items in a variable called listSize, but does not update dynamically.

```
invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
    var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
    if ((errors) > 1) {
      $(".numOfErrors").text(errors + " errors have");
    } else {
      $(".numOfErrors").text(errors + " error has");
    }
 },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sw87W/159/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve the behaviour you require you could call the `valid()` method on each `keypress` in the text inputs and when a `change` happens on the select:

```
$('input:text').keypress(function() {
    $('#form-jsvalidate').valid();
});

$('select').change(function() {
    $('#form-jsvalidate').valid();
})
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sw87W/161/)

Comment: This works - thank you. In my case this one is the better solution because it validates for the Bootstrap dropdowns as well. Thanks very, very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "`showErrors`" callback

From the official documentation:

```
$("#myform").validate({
    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
        $("#summary").html("Your form contains "
            + this.numberOfInvalids()
            + " errors, see details below.");
        this.defaultShowErrors();
    }
});
```

So for you, you could do this:

```
$("#myform").validate({
    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
        $(".numOfErrors").html(this.numberOfInvalids());
        this.defaultShowErrors();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This works. Going to read up. For anyone else interested, link for convenience: https://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.showErrors/ Thanks again!